# Works for https and not http

Tags: wcf, http, https

I have deployed the service in the QA environment and when I browse the file using http://localhost/CustomerService/CustomerService.svc file, It displays the result as expected. Whereas if I browse the same page other than from the server, I'm getting Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. 
a. I have tried pinging to that server - Messages are sent and Received.

Any input on this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the endpoints in the config?

2 options:

Have two endpoints one with http address and one with https

OR

Remove the endpoints totally, and test.